# How to add times to a Ribbon drop-down

Tags: c#, add-in, ribbonx

Add-in for Excel project.
Ribbon is XML-based.
I added a drop-down to the Ribbon:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab label="MyTab" id="tab0">
        <group id="MyGroup"                         
          <dropDown id="MyItems" label="My Items"/>
        </group>        
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

How do I fill in the drop-down with items?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible ways to define the dropdown control on the ribbon:

**1. Static.** For example:

```
<dropDown id="ddStatic" label="Static dropdown"> 
    <item id="ddItem1" label="Item 1" imageMso="HappyFace"/> 
    <item id="ddItem2" label="Item 2" imageMso="Info"/> 
</dropDown>
```

**2. Dynamic.** You need to specify ribbon callbacks, for example, the `getItemCount` should look like the following one:

```
C#: int GetItemCount(IRibbonControl control)

VBA: Sub GetItemCount(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef count)

C++: HRESULT GetItemCount([in] IRibbonControl *pControl, [out, retval] long *count)

Visual Basic: Function GetItemCount(control As IRibbonControl) As Integer
```

It determines how many items will appear in a drop-down.

Also you may need to implement the `getItemID`, `getItemLabel` - sets the label for items in a drop-down, `getSelectedItemIndex` - returns the index of the selected item, `getSelectedItemID`, `onAction` - fires when an item is selected in a drop-down. You may find these callbacks described in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12))
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12))
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12))